# CMake fails with Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

I am trying to build something using the Android NDK standalone toolchain. However, I am running into these errors.

```
        CMake Warning at cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:387 (message):
      Using value of obsolete variable ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT as initial
      value for ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN.  Please note, that
      ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_ROOT can be completely removed in future versions of
      the toolchain.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:476 (__INIT_VARIABLE)
      /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:86 (include)
      CMakeLists.txt:16 (PROJECT)


    CMake Error at cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:412 (FILE):
      file STRINGS file
      "/Users/vgokhale/Desktop/android-ndk-r8e/sysroot/usr/include/android/api-level.h"
      cannot be read.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      cmake/android.toolchain.cmake:548 (__DETECT_NATIVE_API_LEVEL)
      /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.10.2/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:86 (include)
      CMakeLists.txt:16 (PROJECT)

CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/Users/vgokhale/Desktop/torch-android/src/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:/Users/vgokhale/Desktop/torch-android/src/build/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

There are two sets of errors. I don't have any idea where to begin with the first set. The *android.toolchain.cmake* file looks into sysroot by default, but Android is not installed there, and neither does Google require me to install it there.

Regarding the *CMAKE** variables, I found that most solutions involve installing Developer Tools, which I already have. I tried manually setting the *CXX* and *CC* variables, but that did not help.

Where should I start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'll do a bit of guesswork here, but I think you're using http://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/ and you're calling it with ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN while providing it the path to your NDK. If I'm right, that's the problem.

You should either call it with ANDROID_NDK and provide the path to your NDK.
The android-cmake documentation suggests that this is the way to go.

**or**

Keep calling it with ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN, but providing it the path to an installed toochain (something created with make-standalone-toolchain.sh)

If you want to go this way, you can find information about creating standalone toolchains in docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html in your installed NDK.

Comment: Where should I point ANDROID_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN at Windows? I set "C:\cygwin64\bin", but didn't work. I still have issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4070#issuecomment-274723770